# iOS 9.0 - Remove top bar from UIAlertController action sheet

Tags: ios, ios9, uialertcontroller

When creating an action sheet with `UIAlertController`, I'm seeing a top bar always show. This SO post suggests setting the title to `nil` - this might work on iOS 8.0, but I'm seeing a top bar on iOS 9.0.

[image]

Comment: The alert controller's title isn't used with the action sheet. It's the message you need to worry about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `message` to `nil` also:

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet= [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                 message:nil
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *actionSheetButton1 = [UIAlertAction
                                     actionWithTitle:@"Button 1"
                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Button 1 pressed");
                                     }];
UIAlertAction *actionSheetButton2 = [UIAlertAction
                                     actionWithTitle:@"Button 2"
                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Button 2 pressed");
                                     }];
UIAlertAction *actionSheetButton3 = [UIAlertAction
                                     actionWithTitle:@"Close Button"
                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Close Button pressed");
                                     }];

[actionSheet addAction:actionSheetButton1];
[actionSheet addAction:actionSheetButton2];
[actionSheet addAction:actionSheetButton3];
[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: i overlooked that i had set the message to `@""` - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you also set `message` to `nil`? 
This should do the trick, at least it works for me iOS9 (iPhone 6):

```
[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                message:nil
                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
```